# Silverlight - implicit style inheritance problem

Tags: silverlight, styles, implicit-style

If I have a subclass of `ContextMenu` (for example) called `MyContextMenu` and I define a style in my `MergedDictionaries` with `TargetType=ContextMenu`, why does this style not apply to instances of `MyContextMenu`?

It does work for all of the instances of the base class, but not any of the subclasses.

I can create additional styles and use `BasedOn`, but that isn't clean. It seems like it should work without that.

I have made sure that my subclasses call the base constructor, and have verified `DefaultStyleKey` to be the type of my base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implicit-Styles-in-Silverlight-4.aspx):

> Note, that the TargetType must match exactly for a typed style to be applied. For example, if you specify the Style’s Key, then it’s ok for the target element to be a subclass of the TargetType. But a typed style typically gets applied to elements which type matches exactly! This is done to prevent surprises. For example, you might have created a Style for all ToggleButtons in your application and you don’t want this style to be applied to any CheckBoxes (which derives from the ToggleButton).

The same can be read in [the official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (halfway down)

Comment: Of course the answer is in the only place I don't look. Thanks, I suppose there's nothing to be done then. At least we have `BasedOn`.